# How to check the POST/DELETE rest call in firefox with POSTER add-on?

Tags: rest, firefox, firefox-addon

how to check the rest call in poster of firefox,

This is the POST rest call,

http://a.b.c.d:8081/abc/data/otn/connections/internallinks/?request.preventCache=1403603713780

Body is,
{"connectionName":"","serviceRate":"OTU2","tid":"EQMPSS#OCS","fromport1":"OCH-1-1-1-1 ","toport1":"OCH-1-1-3-1","toport2":"","crossRegenPort":"","protectionPort":"","vaPort":"","mvacPort":""}

Comment: Can you please elaborate? It is unclear to me what you're asking, except that you want to do something the the Poster add-on for Firefox?

Comment: Did you try using a http header sniffer tool like __[LiveHTTPHeaders](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/)__? This will show you whats going through and as what (POST/GET/DELETE/whatever). "Browser Toolbox" also has `Net` messages, but I prefer "LiveHTTPHeaders". Nice thing about "Browser Toolbox" though is you can see the response, you can't see that in LiveHTTPHeaders. To access Browser Toolbox enable dev prefs of course then go to the developer menu in panel and click "Browser Toolbox" you will be prompted to confirm "Incoming Connection" allow it.